# Write access not permitted in Windows 7 for CakePHP app

Tags: php, cakephp, windows-7, xampp

I primarily use Mac OSX for programming and then test it in windows periodically. I just installed XAMPP on a Windows 7 computer and I'm getting the following errors

```
Warning: _cake_core_cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_en-us' to File cache in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\testproj\lib\Cake\Cache\Cache.php

Warning:  C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\testproj\lib\Cake\Cache\persistent is not writable in  C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\testproj\lib\Cake\Cache\Engine\FileEngine.php
```

I opened up the testproj folder properties and unchecked Read Only and applied it to all folders/subfolders. I tried to open the Cake application again and the same error message was displaying so I checked the folder properties again and it had a square in the Read-Only box, not a check mark. Does that signify anything? I'm not sure what exactly the square means instead of a check mark.

I am signed into the administrator account on this computer. Is there some kind of command similar to chmod -R 777 for windows?

Thanks

**Update - I changed the installation from Program Files to C:\xampp... and I still get the errors. I then created a partition and installed xampp to G:\xampp... and the error still exists**

Answer (score 1):

Using C:\ and especially the Program Files folder is a really bad idea for developing with PHP on Windows. Use another partition or at least a folder outside of system internal folders.
There is a reason WAMP and most tools by default try to install themselves in `C:\wamp\` etc.

Edit: also try to avoid folder names with spaces in them like the windows-stupid "Program Files" default folder. And mind your casing, even if that is not directly visible in Windows, it will otherwise kill your app when going live with it on a unix server.

Comment: I'll try doing that. Why is it a bad idea though?

Comment: Isn't that obvious from your question? Windows has some special "security" measures for those system folders. Your question would be obsolete if you didn't try to fight windows here :)
PS: Running your normal windows account as admin is still a bad idea - use a normal account and only use the admin one if necessary.

Comment: As I said, I never use the primary partition C:\ for that reason. If you - and as a developer you usually should - are able to use a different partition, that will most likely solve this issue.

Comment: I convinced my buddy to let me create a partition. Unfortunately that still didn't fix it. I logged into a regular user account and as admin, still the errors exist.

Comment: Did you clear the whole cache? So the files can be set up freshly without any wrong permissions set?